# link_to image_tag add Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, link-to

I am trying to add a link to my image but doesnt really sure how I should do it. This is what I have currently.

```
<%= link_to image_tag product.photo.url(:thumb) if product.photo.present? %><br/>
```

I want it to have the same link as 'Show'

```
<%= link_to 'Show', product %><br/>
```

Any advise how I could do it? Trying to clear up the confusion as it might seem to be a duplicate of another question. I am trying to link the product image to its own product information page instead of the image link itself.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my own question by using this. Hope it could help anyone who is looking for a similar solution.

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.photo.url(:thumb)), product if product.photo.present? %><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to product do %>
  <%= image_tag product.photo.url(:thumb) %>
<% end %>
```